CMD automatically closes when trying to run Flutter doctor
Downloaded flutter & Git correctly on both ends & tried to run flutter doctor to make sure everything run correctly but errors continue to pop up.
When i run in CMD: the terminal almost immediately closes, however when it do git + git --version everything seems fine. For power shell is the same story on difference is when i run flutter doctor there is tells me "Unable to find git in your PATH". I even tried adding the git to to path environment but still nothing. for the environment variable im running them all from system variable's. Path environment Variable . [This all starts from he top going down]
edit: I open CMD terminal and enter | C:\Users\t_fle> flutter doctor |then terminal closes.
I use powershell & it gives me this | PS C:\Users\t_fle> flutter doctor
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH
From top down in system Variables for environment variables |
F:\CODING\Git\cmd
F:\flutter_windows_3.24.3-stable\flutter\bin
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

i've had similar issues like this, this is because you put your flutter installation folder in different driver. I see you save your flutter in F drive, and your powershell is in C drive. Try to put your flutter in C Drive.

Besides, try to be more specific: what specific command (including path details) fails and what is the exact error?

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

@gopelkujo
just added| C:\Program Files\flutter_windows_3.24.3-stable\flutter\bin| to the environment variables, & added flutter to the c drive & still nothing

@JosefZ | Hey sorry but this is my first time using stack overflow, what exactly is it that im suppose to remove for this post

@iRon the exact error i get on power shell is | PS C:\Windows\System32> flutter doctor Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. For CMD its impossible to see the error because the moment i run the flutter doctor command it immediately closes out
